# Which one is correct: "Introduction on" or "Introduction to" or "introduction about"

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, sentence-structure

I always try to use "introduction" however, I just afraid that I cannot use it in a correct way.

For example, I would like to say that this section introduces a short background about something:

> 1) This section presents a short introduction **to** something.
>
> 2) This section presents a short introduction **on** something.
>
> 3) This section presents a short introduction **about** something.

Which one is correct?

Comment: I would use *about* or *to* (in case you don't get a proper answer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Introduction" may be a noun, but it comes from the verb *to introduce*. It can refer to different things:

1. The *action* of introducing someone to another someone, or something
2. A specific written or prepared piece of text or speech with the purpose of providing introductory information.

Let's say for example that you had prepared an entry-level presentation designed for people with little or no knowledge of the subject matter at all. You could describe the entire presentation as:

> An introduction *to* [subject]

As a second example, let's say that your prepared presentation is broken down into different sections, the first section of which is designed to welcome your audience and brief them on some essential matters before the rest of the presentation. This first section may be called *the introduction*, and you may say of that section:

> The introduction is *about* [subjects covered in this section]

The difference in the two is that the first is using the word "introduction" to describe the *action* of introducing people *to* a subject, while the second is using the word "introduction" as the *name* of something which is *about* a subject or subjects.

In your personal example, I would say the correct rendition is:

> This section presents (or "*includes*", or simply "*is*") a short introduction *to* [something]

Comment: I’d agree that’s _a_ correct rendition, but I wouldn’t call it “the” correct rendition.